# How to configure a openvpn server static IP for hosts that have dynamic public ips without using Dyndns or some other tools?

Tags: networking, openvpn, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I need to establish a SSH connection with my vpnserver. How to configure a *openvpn* server static IP for hosts that have dynamic public ips without using *Dyndns* or some tools like that. So that I can connect the vpn server by SSH with static vpnserver IP and even if the public IP changes the connection doesn't break.

Comment: I, for one, fail to parse your question. You seem to state the server hosting your OpenVPN instance is about to have a dynamic public IP and then you ask how to configure that server to have a static IP, right? If yes, that's a clear contradiction—that is, you can't. Or have I really failed to grasp the essense of your question?

Comment: by hosts do you mean the ones behind the VPN (internal servers)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without establishing a statically-addressed host. Otherwise, you could script your dynamic to broadcast to you its new address, but your client's IP would not be truly static anymore.